# Searching for twitter client.favorites api, dont knw how to use it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, api, twitter

I am not able to run  `client.favorites` Its a twitter api and i want to like status of users who tweeted.

My task is to write a script in Ruby that uses the Twitter search API to search for the any phare, then favorite that tweet and follow the account that tweeted.

I managed to do follow and searching part. But i am not sure about how to favorite particular comment.

There are couple of links i want to share with you which i tried.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/favorites/create

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/User

and this is my code

```
client.favorites("#{tweet.id}","#{tweet.user.screen_name}",#{tweet.url}")
```

Comment: what is the error?  you started to add an image but there's nothing there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `tweet` is the object that holds the tweet to favorite, then the operation is as simple as

```
client.fav tweet
```

I found this on [Make your Twitter Bot](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/create-twitter-bot-auto)

Comment: thanks , it worked. Can you suggest any twitter api tutorials. I want to do exact search and fav their tweets.

Comment: Can you tell me how you want to search the tweets; based on what parameters? If you can, frame another question. I'll answer it. If the above answer worked, you can mark it as useful so that others can also benefit from it.